# How to adjust display width of renderPrint in R-markdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am writing an interactive R-markdown report using some R shiny components, to show some exploratory analysis results.

I used `renderPrint()` to display the results from `describe()` as below.

```
renderPrint({
    check_list <- c("CustomerSatisfaction", "AssignedServiceFamily", "ProductName","ReportedSource")
    df_overview <- df[check_list]%>%
                 subset(ReportedSource %in% input$select0) %>%
                 subset(AssignedServiceFamily %in% input$select1) %>% 
                 subset(ProductName %in% input$select2)
    describe(df_overview)
})
```

**CustomerSatisfaction** is an character variable with 5 different values. However, the r markdown output can not display all the 5 values at the same line, though there still are some remaining space in the width of page, as shown in the below screenshot.
[image: display issue]

I have tried to increase the file width by setting up option as below. While the width of the markdown output increased accordingly, `renderPrint()` still display my results for **CustomerSatisfaction** in two parts. Only the width of grey background area increased.

```
<style>
    body .main-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
</style>
```

I also tried to  set up width option for `renderPrint()` as below, but it didn't work for me.

```
renderPrint({mycode}, width = 800)
```

Any idea how I can set up to display it in one part as below?
[image]

My YAML header is set as below.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y-%m-%d')`"
output: html_document
theme: cosmo
runtime: shiny
---
```